# Media front preset creation

Tags: 7, media

Clean installation of `Drupal 7.41`, only installed modules needed for *[mediafront](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront)*. When I create a preset and hit save the player preview is blank and cannot click *Preset information*, *Player setting* or *player to player*.

But no error in logs.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In order to get good answers, you might consider improving your question, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help). E.g. you might add screenshots to make your problem easier to understand.